# java enum exception

Tags: java, sql

I have enum class

```
    package org.testTask.DTO;
    
    public enum Publisher {
        MOSCOW("МОСКВА"),
        ST_PETERSBURG("ПИТЕР"),
        O_REILLY("O’REILLY");
    
        private String name;
    
        private long id;
    
        Publisher(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = ordinal();
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
```

SQL request

```
protected Publisher getObject(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    return Publisher.valueOf(resultSet.getString("NAME"));
}
```

and variables in the database with values "МОСКВА", "ПИТЕР", "O’REILLY". But it gives me an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.testTask.DTO.Publisher.ПИТЕР`
I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: It is confusing to have a method called `getName()` in an enum, considering there will also be a method `name()`. You should rename it.

Comment: Also, don't use the `ordinal()` for the `id` value. For one, why duplicate it? But for another, it's brittle to changes in the enum (e.g. what if some kind soul alphabetizes the list?). Supply an explicit id value to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`valueOf` does not work that way. You have to given it the name of one of the enum members, i.e., `valueOf("MOSCOW")`.

What you call 'name' is not **the name** of the enum.  The name is the thing you can write in source code, Publisher.MOSCOW.

To facilitate lookups by (Russian) name, you need to search through the list of enum members for one with a matching (Russian) name.   If you have many more than 3, a map would be useful for efficiency, but I would not bother for a small number of publishers.

Comment: I need to return the publisher with the same name as the value in the database in the "NAME" column. So I pass "NAME" to resultSet.getString () to get the string in that column

Comment: Fine, but you're stuck.  You could declare `enum Publisher { МОСКВА, ПИТЕР … }` rather than MOSCOW, ST_PETERSBURG, but that is not possible for O'REILLY.  So you need to write something that translates from what you've got in your database into the names of the enum members in your Java program

Answer (score 1):

`.valueOf` method returns the enum constant of the specified enumtype with the specified name, means `.valueOf("ST_PETERSBURG")` not from the field `name`.

You need to match the `name` field of enum constants with database value and get the enum

```
protected Publisher getObject(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    String enumName = resultSet.getString("NAME")
    return  Arrays.stream(Publisher.values())
                            .filter(e -> e.getName().equals(enumName))
                            .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Enum members are the names in English, not the ones in Russian.
you should pass `MOSCOW`, `ST_PETERSBURG` or `O_REILLY` to  `valueOf()`